# Counting groups in columns in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I have a dataframe df:

```
     prds
0    E01
1    E02
2    E03
3    E04
4    E01
5    E02
6    E03
7    E04
8    F01
9    F02
10   F03
11   F04
12   F05
```

I would like to have an count on each group in the column 'prds' on another column 'match', hence:

```
    prds  match
0    E01    1
1    E02    2
2    E03    3
3    E04    4
4    E01    1
5    E02    2
6    E03    3
7    E04    4
8    F01    1
9    F02    2
10   F03    3
11   F04    4
12   F05    5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated please. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each group is possible defined by ending by `1` value is possible use [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and pass to [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['match'] = df.groupby(df['prds'].str.endswith('1').cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
print (df)
   prds  match
0   E01      1
1   E02      2
2   E03      3
3   E04      4
4   E01      1
5   E02      2
6   E03      3
7   E04      4
8   F01      1
9   F02      2
10  F03      3
11  F04      4
12  F05      5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract digits:

```
df['match'] = df['prds'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype('int')
```

Output:

```
   prds  match
0   E01      1
1   E02      2
2   E03      3
3   E04      4
4   E01      1
5   E02      2
6   E03      3
7   E04      4
8   F01      1
9   F02      2
10  F03      3
11  F04      4
12  F05      5
```